# provide time gap between two function

Tags: android

How to provide time gap between two functions?

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
                r1.startAnimation(slide_up);

                Intent i = new Intent(Main_page.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
```

Comment: Add some description to your question. Which functions? What is a `gap` in your case?

Comment: Your question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

Add an `AnimationListener` to your animation and trigger the wanted methods in `OnAnimationEnd()`

Take a look at this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html

Answer (score 0):

You can Use [**`Handler`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to delay

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                r1.startAnimation(slide_up);

                 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Intent i = new Intent(Main_page.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                }, 3000); // times in milliseconds

            }
```

Second way Using [**`Animation.AnimationListener`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html)

**Sample code**

```
slideUpAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

       Intent i = new Intent(Main_page.this, MainActivity.class);
       startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
});
```

Third way

```
slideUpAnimation.withEndAction(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
          Intent i = new Intent(Main_page.this, MainActivity.class);
          startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
    slide_up.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {

        Intent i = new Intent(Main_page.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```